# How to use cutter concept -UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

How to use cutter concept in RUTA. I had go through the documentation but I'm not clear.Can anyone explain it briefly.

Comment: By cutter concept, you mean RutaCutter analysis engine?

Comment: @Peter Yeah,RutaCutter analysis engine.

Answer (score 0):

[RutaCutter](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.cutter) is a simple analysis engine for modifying the document text in a CAS. Well, the document text cannot be modified, thus a new view is created where the modifications will be stored. There are three configuration parameter: The name of the input view, e.g., `_InitialView` (your text), the name of the output view, e.g., `cutted` (where the result will be stored), and a complete type name. Only text covered by annotations of that type will be stored in the output view. All other text spans will be 'cutted'. The offsets of annotations within the remaining text will be updated.

Here's a code example:

```
// setup
JCas jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
AnalysisEngine cutter = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngine(RutaCutter.class, RutaCutter.PARAM_KEEP, TruePositive.class.getName());
jcas.setDocumentText("Some text.");
Ruta.apply(jcas.getCas(), "SW{-> TruePositive};");
cutter.process(jcas);

// testing
Collection<TruePositive> select = JCasUtil.select(jcas, TruePositive.class);
Assert.assertEquals(1, select.size());
TruePositive truePositive = select.iterator().next();
Assert.assertEquals(5, truePositive.getBegin());

JCas cuttedView = jcas.getView("cutted");
Assert.assertEquals("text", cuttedView.getDocumentText());
select = JCasUtil.select(cuttedView, TruePositive.class);
Assert.assertEquals(1, select.size());
truePositive = select.iterator().next();
Assert.assertEquals(0, truePositive.getBegin());

jcas.release();
cutter.destroy();
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*